# Trouble casting UIView in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting

I have a class called `FooView` which is a subclass of `UIView` and I'm trying to cast a `UIView` object into `FooView`.

I do this as follows

```
FooView *myView = (FooView*) MyViewController.view
NSLog(@"Leg is a class of %@",NSStringFromClass([myView class])); // Get UIView here.
```

The ivar of `MyViewController` is a `UIView` type.

I get a UIView result, any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm not sure I've got the idea. What do you need: turn a basic UIView to a FooView in run-time? Or just a cast pointer? The first one is impossible, to achieve the second you must simply point MyViewController.view to a view of "FooView" type (even if an outlet is typed as UIView).

Comment: When you mean point the view ivar, do you mean what I did above?

Comment: Well, yes. Sometimes you have a property (or a variable) of a basic type, but you KNOW that the actual type is different - that's vere the casting work as expected. But as you receive unexpected type, I assume that you don't have proper object in the controller.view. To operate as you expect, it must be of the FooView type - check the XIB or the code which builds up controller view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is a compile-time operation. It doesn't magically change the type of the object. It's mostly for compile time checking and a little runtime magic. `myView` is still a `UIView`, not a `FooView`.

These two lines in your question should give you your answer:

> The ivar of MyViewController is a UIView type. I get a UIView result

All Objective-C objects have a pointer called `isa` that points to an object of type `Class`. Casting does not change that pointer, nor does it change the size of the object.

If you want to use a `FooView`, you need to change the property type in your controller and if you're using Interface Builder, change the type of the UIView in the inspector on the right.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to send selectors defined by `FooView` to this object? I get an invalid selector error in this case, but in the past when I tried this I didn't.

Comment: No. `UIView` doesn't have those methods. Remember that at the end of the day, an object can't just magically change classes to a subclass. It's still a `UIView`, no matter what you tell the compiler. It will crash. You've promised the compiler that the class is actually a `FooView`, but all you've done is lie to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loadView method in MyViewController that creates a FooView and sets it to self.view. It's for when you're not using a NIB.